Digital phase_locked loop based on CORDIC algorithm
I want to know whether the digital phase_locked loop based on CORDIC algorithm  can achieve the correct phase locking function when the input signal SNR is very low(lower than 25dB or lower than 30dB).

couple of problems: "PLL based on CORDIC algorithm" doesn't really tell us what you had in mind. What in that PLL will be implemented in a CORDIC fashion? As Tim explained in the comment to your last question, "CORDIC" is just a method of implementing some functions – sine, cosine, arctan, square root,… It's not clear what you mean with "CORDIC based PLL"? Second issue is that you say 25 dB is "low SNR". Now, that's a bit surprising – 25 dB means that your signals are, on average, nearly 18 times as large in magnitude than your noise. Are you sure? In the context of PLLs, this is great SNR.

(I get the feeling you're not clear about the what a PLL is, and what CORDIC is. Am I wrong? If I'm right, I think the best first step would be to research PLLs, then how you use PLLs for phase recovery.)

Thank you for your answer. I think you are right. I don't understand PLL.
Could you give some advise or studying step for me to research PLL?

That's usually covered in most digital communications textbooks. Do you happen to have a go-to textbook from e.g. a university course? Otherwise, you'd probably be fine with Proakis' textbook.
